# List index out of range Asyncio

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I am webscraping a large number of elements on a web page. When I loop over 15K elements, I always get an error on the last element. It works well in loops of low iterations. The asyncio method I have used is as follows

```
async def getInfo_async(links: List[str]) -> list:
    res = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=48) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            tasks = [
                loop.run_in_executor(executor,getInfo, *(link,session)) for link in links
                ]
            for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
                res.append(response)

    return res

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(getInfo_async(list1))
res = loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

List1 is a list of URLs.
In the getInfo method, I extract different information and store them in different lists through an append.  The error occurs specifically in this extraction

```
try:
        team = soup.find("span", {"class": "data-header__club"}).find("a")["title"]
    except (AttributeError,IndexError,TypeError):
        team = "Retired"
    if team in ["Without Club", "None","Retired","-"]:
        joined = None
        contract_expires = None
    else:
        joined = [el.text.split(": ")[-1] \
            for el in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "data-header__label"}) \
            if "joined" in el.text.lower()][0]
        if joined == "-":
            joined = None
        else:
            joined = datetime.datetime.strptime(joined, '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        contract_expires = [el.text.split(": ")[-1] \
            for el in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "data-header__label"}) \
            if "expires" in el.text.lower()][0]
        if contract_expires == "-":
            contract_expires = None
        else:
            contract_expires = datetime.datetime.strptime(contract_expires, '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    coList.append(joined)
    exList.append(contract_expires)
    teList.append(team)
```

The error is the following one:

[image]

Comment: it means el.text.split(": ") is null or empty. Add a handling when it happens.

Comment: I have it 3 lines below, but first I need to extract the value of the joined variable. If that's the error, shouldn't it jump further down and not on that line? @jose_bacoy